# "#include errors detected" and "cannot open source file"

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, configuration, include, eigen

```
#include <cmath>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
```

line2: "#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting."

line2&3: "cannot open source file"

My CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22.1)
project (Transformation)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
message("${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable (Transformation main.cpp)
```

and its output is

```
...
[cmake] /usr/local/include/eigen3
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: 
...
```

It seems cmake has found eigen3 with path "/usr/local/include/eigen3" but #include still reports errors.

I have also added eigen3 alias path into the includePath. My c_cpp_properties.json is

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I checked some relative problems but haven't found a solution. I don't know why the files cannot be opened as they exactly exist and I have edited the includePath. Are my configurations wrong?

Many thanks!!!

---

Update: My **solution** is to replace `include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)` in CMakeLists.txt with `include_directories("/usr/local/include")`

Nonetheless, I don’t understand why it doesn't work if I remain `include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)` but remove the `eigen3/` prefix in the includes. Besides, it seems what I wrote in c_cpp_properties.json doesn't affect anything.

---

Update: I try to replace `include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)` in CMakeLists.txt with `include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})` as suggested and remove the `eigen3/` prefix in the includes. And now only line2 reports error "'Eigen/Core' file not found". It is strange since line2 & line3 should be in similar cases.

Comment: Try removing the `eigen3/` prefix on the includes. You already seem to have that subdirectory in the includePath.

Comment: Or replace "/usr/local/include/eigen3" with "/usr/local/include" in your json or just add the latter

Comment: So is there a `/usr/local/include/eigen3/eigen3/Eigen/Core` file?

Comment: After you fix the include directory, you should add your include path to your tasks.json as well depending on how you are building.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you! I fixed my includePath as shown above but the problem is still there.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you! I fixed my includePath as shown above but the problem is still there.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! I fixed my includePath as shown above but the problem is still there. Is it necessary to use tasks.json as I am using CMake? I knew nothing about tasks.json and just found "CMake projects do not use this file because all the build commands are specified in CMakeLists.txt" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/tasks-vs-json-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: If you are using the CMake tools addon then you will not set the path in tasks.json

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. I added the CMake relevant in my question description. Is my CMakeLists.txt right?

Comment: Maybe the initial comment to this question is the solution.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! I tried that before but it didn't work. I've found the solution although I don’t quite understand why removing eigen3/ prefix doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you forgot to **dereference** (via `${..}`) the variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` in `include_directories` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! I've tried this but there is still an error. I updated the details in the question description.

Comment: Removing the `eigen` part probably screws up the includes done inside the eigen headers itself. Probably adding both `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` and the parent dir would work: `include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}/..")` But doesn't eigen provide imported targets you can just link which provide the required properties (i.e. simply doing `target_link_libraries(Transform PRIVATE Eigen)` without any additional `include_directories()` commands).

Comment: @fabian Many thanks! `include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}/..")`works and only parent dir `include_directories("${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}/..")` also works. But simply doing `target_link_libraries()` without `include_directories()` will report the same errors "#include errors detected" and "cannot open source file".